# What should be the timeout for window resize dragging?

Tags: javascript, performance, resize, window-resize

I have this code that fires when the user has probably stopped resizing the window (by dragging). It uses a 100ms timeout to not fire at every single window resize event. I'd like to find the balance between swiftness and unnecessary runs of the code which is somewhat heavy. So from a user experience standpoint, how many ms should I set this to?

```
var resizeTO = false;
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(resizeTO !== false){
        clearTimeout(resizeTO);
    }
    resizeTO = setTimeout(function(){
        // MY CODE
    }, 100); 
});
```

Comment: Regardless of your method, the performance and "smoothness" of this algorithm will ultimately depend on the client computer. My personal opinion is that there won't be a "magic number" for everyone.

Comment: You seem to be setting up the `setTimeout`, but clearing it immediately as the `resize` fires, so your throttling will be ineffective.

Comment: I do that because I don't want it to fire at every window resize event, I just re-add the timeout so it can cool down if the user has stopped resizing.

Comment: @Dutchie432 I think it's more dependant on human behavior i.e. how fast people move the mouse and what time since the last movement could be considered 'they stopped'. The performance of the code I call is another thing.

Comment: @Firsh: Yes, I understand the concept, but let's say the event fires `100` times while the window is resized, Every time it fires, it's immediately  clearing the `setTimeout` that you set at the previous invocation. Therefore you're creating a bunch of wasted `setTimeout`s, and it'll never actually run until `100ms` after the resize ended.

Comment: ...or are you saying you *want* to prevent the code from running entirely while the window is resized? Maybe I was misunderstanding the intent of the code.

Comment: How should I do it then? I only want to prevent `// MY CODE` from running while it's being resised, and run only once when it's no longer getting resized anymore.

Comment: Alright, then you're doing it correctly, but then the size of the timer wouldn't really matter quite so much. If you want to prevent it entirely... well there's no way to predict if the user will pause for a short or long while while resizing. It'll come down to how much of a delay you're personally comfortable with the user experiencing after the resize stops. The longer the delay, the more likely to catch brief pauses.

Comment: ...and your time may be better spent optimizing the `// MY CODE` part if it's a heavy operation as you say.

Comment: @Firsh Go use a 10 year old Windows 2000/XP machine and tell me if you still agree :) The smoothness I refer to is the rate at which the screen will actually refresh - which is something you should consider too.

Comment: Check out [this site](http://www.thinkgreenmeeting.com/). They use the same technique in their `init.js` script. It fires the `adjustframe()` method, and uses a `300ms` delay. When resizing stops, there's a short pause, but it doesn't negatively affect the experience at all IMO. I'd just experiment and see what delay makes the most sense given your site.